# AIML Pattern not matching

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, chatbot, aiml

I have been trying to develop a chat bot using Node.js,AIML and socket.io. Now the problem is, when I try to match a pattern when giving input, it just matches the '*' pattern and no other pattern. Please help. I have attached my server.js file and the client - index.html file for reference. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1deMr.png) is my .aiml file used for defining patterns.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var aimlHigh = require('./node_modules/aiml-high')
/*var interpreter = new aimlHigh({name:'Bot', age:'42'}, 'Goodbye');
interpreter.loadFiles(['./test.aiml.xml']);*/
//var AIMLInterpreter = require('aimlinterpreter');
var AIMLFunctions = require(__dirname + "/models/aiml.js")

users = [];
connections = [];
sockID = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
console.log('Server is running...')

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var interpreter = new aimlHigh(AIMLFunctions.getAimlVars());
interpreter.loadFiles(AIMLFunctions.getAimlFiles());
/*var aimlInterpreter = new AIMLInterpreter(AIMLFunctions.getAimlVars());
aimlInterpreter.loadAIMLFilesIntoArray(AIMLFunctions.getAimlFiles());*/

//socket connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  connections.push(socket);
  console.log('%s clients connected...', connections.length);
  //sockID.push(socket.id);
  var greet = AIMLFunctions.getRandomGreet();
  console.log(greet);

  //disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {

    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('Disconnected; %s clients connected...', connections.length);
  });

  //send messages
  socket.on('content', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var text = data;
    //io.sockets.emit('New Message',{msg: data}); //sabke_liye
    //io.to(sockID[0]).emit('New Message',{msg: data}); //ID_using_connection
    io.to(socket.id).emit('New Message', {
      msg: data
    });

    //text = text.replace(/\s/g,'');



    interpreter.findAnswer(data, function(answer, wildCardArray, input) {
      console.log(answer + ' | ' + wildCardArray + ' | ' + input);
      io.to(socket.id).emit('New Message', {
        msg: answer
      });
    });



    /*aimlInterpreter.findAnswerInLoadedAIMLFiles(data, function(answer, wildCardArray, input){
     io.to(socket.id).emit('New Message', {msg: answer});
    });*/





    /*text1 = text.toLowerCase();

    if(text1 == "hi")
    {
     io.to(socket.id).emit('New Message', {msg:'Hey! Nice to meet you :)'});
     //io.sockets.emit('New Message',{msg: "hello"});
    }

    if(text1 == "howareyou?")
    {
     io.to(socket.id).emit('New Message', {msg:'I am cool! You?'});
     //io.sockets.emit('New Message',{msg: "I'm Good, Thanks!"});
    }

    if(text1 == "iamwet!")
    {
     io.to(socket.id).emit('New Message', {msg:"Oh! It's raining. I see."});
     //io.sockets.emit('New Message',{msg: "I'm Good, Thanks!"});
    }*/

  });

  //NewUser
  /*socket.on('new user',function(data,callback){
   callback(true);
   socket.username = data;
   users.push(socket.username);
   updateUsernames();
  });

  function updateUsernames(){
   io.sockets.emit('get users', usernames)
  }*/
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>RelianceBot</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <!--  <style>
  #messageArea{
   display:none;
  }
 </style> -->
</head>

<body style="margin-top: 50px; background-color: red">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="messageArea" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">
          <h1 style="font-family:fantasy"><strong>xBOT</strong></h1>
          <ul class="list-group" id="users"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 150px; padding-right: 25px">
      <form id="messageForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label style="font-family: cursive; color: whitesmoke">Type Here:</label>

          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="message" />

          <br>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var socket = io.connect();
      var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
      var $message = $('#message');
      var $chat = $('#chat');
      /*var $messageArea = $('#messageArea');
      var $userFormArea = $('#userFormArea');
      var $userForm = $('#userForm');
      var $users = $('#userForm');
      var $username = $('#userForm');*/

      //$chat.append('<div class="well">'+$message.val()+'</div>'


      $messageForm.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('content', $message.val());
        $message.val('');
      });


      socket.on('New Message', function(data) {
        $chat.append('<div class="well"><strong>' + data.msg + '</strong></div>')
      });


    });

    $("input").keypress(function(event) {
      if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#messageForm").submit();
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```